# Remove array elements from another array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB object like:

```
{

    "courseName": "ML",
    "user": ObjectId("6087dc4c2ba7a828363c9fca"),
    "questions": [  
        {

            "topics": [
               "a","b"
            ],
        },
        {
            "topics": [
                "a","b","d"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the questions with `courseName` and `user` into questions, I want to remove the topic(s) that matches with the input topic.

How can I do this?

If my input is `["a"]` then the update output should look like:

```
{

    "courseName": "ML",
    "user": ObjectId("6087dc4c2ba7a828363c9fca"),
    "questions": [  
        {

            "topics": [
               "b"
            ],
        },
        {
            "topics": [
                "b","d"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$[]` positional for all elements in `questions` and check condition by `$in` operator

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { 
    "courseName": "ML",
    "user": ObjectId("6087dc4c2ba7a828363c9fca"),
    "questions.topics": { $in: ["a"] } 
  },
  {
    $pull: {
      "questions.$[].topics": { $in: ["a"] }
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PIapK97pRvb)